# Undefined in place of stream observable while working with ng effects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

So Im doing a flow where I'd add new object to other's object collection. So first I have to do some let's say domain related stuff.

I'm sending object to backend then when I'd recieve callback I send antoher action to the store upon which my another Effect should take action.

In this action I should yet again call backend controller with new payload, then the flow should end. The problem occurs on calling the backend. Im recieving following error there:

```
        from update project effect
    project.effects.ts:52 {projectId: "5980ea8390dfb5285402e18b", userId: "admin@wp.pl", drawings: Array(2), projectName: "Test pro"}
    project.service.ts:37 

z update project service
    project.service.ts:38 {projectId: "5980ea8390dfb5285402e18b", userId: "admin@wp.pl", drawings: Array(2), projectName: "Test pro"}drawings: (2) [{…}, Drawing]projectId: "5980ea8390dfb5285402e18b"projectName: "Test pro"userId: "admin@wp.pl"__proto__: Object
    core.es5.js:1084

 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
        at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:73)
        at
```

Im using similiar flow in other part of app (eg. login) and it works ok. Below the code:

```
@Effect() addNewDrawing = this.actions
    .ofType(ProjectActions.ADD_NEW_DRAWING)
    .map(toPayload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getProject))
    .switchMap(([payload, project] : [AddDrawingCommand, Project]) =>
      this.uploadService.upload(payload.file)
        .mergeMap((result:any) : any => {
          project.drawings.push(new Drawing(payload.drawingName, result.drawingUrl, 0));
          console.log(payload)
          console.log('------------------')
          console.log(result)
          console.log(project)
          console.log('------------------')
          return this.store.dispatch(new UpdateProject(project));
        }));

  @Effect() updateProject = this.actions
    .ofType(ProjectActions.UPDATE_PROJECT)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap(payload => {
        console.log('from update project effect');
        console.log(payload);
       return this.projectService.updateProject(payload)
      }
    );
```

everything seems to blow up when calling the projectService:

```
 updateProject(project: Project): Observable<any> {
    console.log('z update project service')
    console.log(project)
    return this.http.put(`${this.projectUrl}/${project.projectId}`, project)
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

but its the same as any other service that work alright.

Comment: I don't think `this.store.dispatch()` returns an Observable, see https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/master/src/store.ts#L35

Comment: your answer put me in the right track, that was the case, finally i dropped the mergemap. Post answer if you want get upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `mergeMap` you're returning a value from the `this.store.dispatch` call but this doesn't return an Observable.

For more info: https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/master/src/store.ts#L35